# Why is this script slowing down the gravity of the rigidbody2d (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the script, it's a simple horizontal movement script.

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;

public float speed;

private float moveHori;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    moveHori = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveHori * speed, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

I don't know why is the gravity slowing down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you set the Y component of the `velocity` to 0 in

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveHori * speed, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
```

rather keep your current Y velocity like

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveHori * speed, rb.velocity.y);
```

Note btw that a velocity is framerate independent and you do not want to multiply by `Time.deltaTime` here! Rather adjust your `speed` so it is the desired Unity units per seconds.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because you made sense of his question while I was still trying. But does setting the y velocity this way not still hold it fixed? Gravity will pull it downward, but it won't accelerate.

Comment: @StevensMiller it doesn't change the velocity within this `FixedUpdate` method but allows the Physics engine itself to alternate this value before or after the execution of this component's `FixedUpdate` call. It should increase over time just as expected. Well, at least that's what I would expect to happen ^^

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing, though. Adding this code to a cube and printing velocity on each FixedUpdate shows it holding steady at 0.0, 0.2.

Comment: @StevensMiller Maybe the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) might help you understand it a bit better. FixedUpdate runs before the internal physics update. The internal physics update will perform object movement, then update the velocity in preparation for the next frame. As long as you're not overwriting the "prepared velocity" with previous frame values, you eliminate the issue.

Comment: Except, again, that's not what it's actually doing. But thanks for the extra info!